# How to get data from only the last row that has been added content to?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code I have right now is getting information from the:

```
                 (2nd row,1st column, last row minus the title row, to the 80th column)
```

`const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,80).getDisplayValues();`

But would like to get information only from the last row that has been added content to it.

How should that look like?

`const data = currentSheet.getRange( ? ,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,80).getDisplayValues();`

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#Get last row data

```
function getlastrowdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheeet Name");
  const data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn())).getValues()[0];
}
```